# Any other "common design archetypes" in Kiznaiver that are shared with other Trigger-related works?

Tags: kiznaiver

scroll down for character images

**Niiyama Niko** seems to be a character that's inspired by *Kill la Kill's* **Mankanshoku Mako** (behavior) and **Harime Nui** (appearance).

**Tenga Hajime** seems to be a dumber version of **Kamina** from *Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann*. Are there any other referances/homages to be found in *Kiznaiver*? For example, maybe something from *Little Witch Academia*?

FYI: *Kill la Kill*, *Kiznaiver*, and *Little Witch Academia* are produced by Trigger, which was founded by members of Gainax, which produced *Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann*.

Niko
[image: Niiyama Niko]

Mako: [the gif I actually wanted to post](http://orig04.deviantart.net/0d7b/f/2014/018/0/2/mako_mankanshoku_funny_gif_by_jkphantom9-d72q886.gif)
Mako
[image: Mankanshoku Mako]

Harime Nui
[image: Harime Nui]

Tenga
[image: Tenga Hajime]

Kamina
[image: Kamina]

Comment: There are no "cameos" in character design, but there are character archetypes. [One of Kiznaiver's character designers](http://myanimelist.net/people/39271/Yoneyama_Mai) worked as an Animation Director and animator on Kill la Kill, and an animator on Little Witch Academia. It's not at all surprising to bring over styles that you are familiar with tho other productions, especially did the designs were well received.